# Help with cursor (circle) orientation while sculpting

Tags: sculpting

I'm following a sculpting tutorial and I'm having a little trouble replicating what the instructor is doing. When he is altering the mesh, the cursor is orienting itself to whatever part of the mesh he's working on. For example, if he's working on the top, the circle will change its orientation to indicate which part of the mesh is being affected.

How can I get my cursor/circle to do that? It stays the same irrespective of which part of the mesh I'm working on.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of Blender are you using? - I haven't done much sculpting but I believe that was introduced in version 2.8.

Comment: I'm using 2.8. Is there a setting to enable it?

Comment: I don't think so but I've just been having a play and noticed that the cursor follows the surface of the object much better if you've applied any subsurface modifier you may have on the object before starting to sculpt.

Comment: I just decided to upgrade my version. Seems to work now. Thanks for your suggestions, though.

Comment: Good! I stay up to date with the long term support version (now 2.83.8) and the latest 2.9 no-beta version (2.90.1). On reflection the following cursor appeared in one of the earlier 2.8 versions.